# Doctrine 2 Versionable on INSERT

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I have implemented successfully an audit trail for my entities using this example: http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-versionable.

Everything works fine, even with relationships.

**The Problem:**

If a record doesn't exists in the database, doctrine 2 is doing an INSERT (as expected), it does also write a audit trail but with resourceId = 0 because it doesn't know the ID of the (new) entity before it's being flushed.

In this case I always loss the first audit of a record and actually never know who/when created the record.

I think the problem is in here:

```
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
{
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() AS $entity) {
        if ($entity instanceof Versionable) {
            $this->_makeSnapshot($entity);
        }
    }

    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() AS $entity) {
        if ($entity instanceof Versionable) {
            $this->_makeSnapshot($entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article you posted to is pretty old.  onFlush is not the appropriate event to listen to.

You want to listen to postPersist, postUpdate, postRemove.  Each will be called for each entity so you don't need to do any of the unit of work stuff.

Better examples here:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/events.html